# How does calling a function or class with multiple () work? python

Tags: python, function

I have the following code:

```
def chain_sum(number):
    result = number

    def wrapper(number_2=None):
        nonlocal result
        if number_2 is None:
            return result
        result += number_2
        return wrapper

    return wrapper


print(chain_sum(5)()) #5
print(chain_sum(5)(2)()) #7
print(chain_sum(5)(100)(-10)()) #95


class chain_sum_0(int):
    def __call__(self, addition=0):
        return chain_sum(self + addition)


print(chain_sum_0(5)) #5
print(chain_sum_0(5)(2)()) #7
print(chain_sum_0(5)(100)(-10)()) #95
```

I want to know how this code works. In particular, why / how do these calls that occur in such a sequence work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling a function with multiple `()`s. You call a function with *one* `()`, and if the return value is callable, you can call *it* immediately. `f()()` is equivalent to `t = f(); t()`.

You can think of `()` as an (pseudo)operator that applies to any callable-valued expression. For example, something like `(f if condition else g)()` is legal, equivalent to `f() if condition else g()`.

In your case, note that the function defined by `chain_sum` returns *itself* when called with an argument, so each call produces an argument you can call again until you finally call it with no arguments, at which point it returns an accumulated value that's been building up in the closure.